# NoSuchMethodException for an available method

Tags: java, jboss7.x, webservice-client

I am using an Open KM app framework for my application. It is strange to see that at times I get NoSuchMethodException in my code for a method that is available. Once I start getting this exception, then it keeps repeating until i restart the server (Jboss7). Once restarted this will work file till some point and then again this exception will happen and keep happening.

Can anybody help in this?

My Exception trace

```
19:34:10,725 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/CAMSWeb].[spring]] (http--192.168.1.62-8080-2) Servlet.service() for servlet spring threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.openkm.ws.client.document.OKMDocument.create(java.lang.String, com.openkm.ws.client.document.Document, [B)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1622) [:1.7.0_09]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodDispatcher.getImplementationMethod(JAXWSMethodDispatcher.java:109)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodDispatcher.bind(JAXWSMethodDispatcher.java:55)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.bindOperation(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:280)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.initializeWSDLOperation(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:254)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeWSDLOperations(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:645)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.initializeWSDLOperations(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:289)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:392)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:499)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:241)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:202)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:90)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:152)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createPort(ServiceImpl.java:464)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:331)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:318)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:99) [jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at com.openkm.ws.client.document.OKMDocument_Service.getOKMDocumentPort(OKMDocument_Service.java:72) [okm-ws-client-6.0.jar:]
```

I have put some other traces as well to know what is the calling class and expected method.. These are the results

```
19:34:10,719 INFO  [stdout] (http--192.168.1.62-8080-2) Trying to fetch method ========      create from class : interface com.openkm.ws.client.document.OKMDocument
19:34:10,719 INFO  [stdout] (http--192.168.1.62-8080-2) Length of the method name  ======== 6
19:34:10,719 INFO  [stdout] (http--192.168.1.62-8080-2) The parameters for the expected method are
19:34:10,719 INFO  [stdout] (http--192.168.1.62-8080-2) >>>>>>>>>.... java.lang.String
19:34:10,719 INFO  [stdout] (http--192.168.1.62-8080-2) >>>>>>>>>....   com.openkm.ws.client.document.Document
19:34:10,719 INFO  [stdout] (http--192.168.1.62-8080-2) >>>>>>>>>.... [B
```

This the result of the getMethods from invoked method endpoint class

```
19:34:10,721 INFO  [stdout] (http--192.168.1.62-8080-2)  Method Name :: create
19:34:10,721 INFO  [stdout] (http--192.168.1.62-8080-2) Parameters.... java.lang.String
19:34:10,721 INFO  [stdout] (http--192.168.1.62-8080-2) Parameters....  com.openkm.ws.client.document.Document
19:34:10,721 INFO  [stdout] (http--192.168.1.62-8080-2) Parameters.... [B
```

As we can see the calling signature is

```
create(String, com.openkm.ws.client.document.Document, byteArray)
```

and the targeted class too has a method with the same signature, but still at times I get this NoSucnMethodException and as said once it comes, then it keeps coming forever till i restart the server.

Any help...

Comment: Are you using Maven by any chance?

Comment: No im not... the build is via ant.. i just have this okm-ws.client.jar in my war

Comment: I'm running into the same issue with CXF & JBoss. It looks like a class loader issue - happens after app is reloaded (occasionally). CXF JaxWsImplementorInfo loads the Service Endpoint Interface (seiClass) with org.apache.cxf.common.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils. This uses the current thread's class loader, e.g., MDB thread, which is retained between apps. So it seems likely the previous class definition is being loaded, which doesn't match the current service interface (due to the different class loader). I'll post a solution if I find one.

Answer (score 0):

`com.openkm.ws.client.document.Document` is an *interface*.  I suspect the implementation is missing from the runtime deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me check what is injected in com.openkm.ws.client.document.Document instance, but the getMethod() api of the Method class should be ok if the target class has a method of the specified signature right? Will he be checking the instance implementation

Comment: At that point, CXF compares the service endpoint interfaces´ (SEI) methods with the actual web service implementation, which must extend the SEI. Therefore having an interface (SEI) here is completely ok. And read the question carefully - this is only happening sometimes! So the implementation is there, but the comparison fails sometimes.